# Why were my suggested tags just git and python?

Tags: bug, suggested-tags

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27877456/344286) a few moments ago.

The suggested tags were git and python, not Mercurial (which my question was about).

Obviously this is super minor - but I did think it strange as I've never had the tag suggestions pick out all of the wrong pieces from my question.

Comment: Perhaps only the top two suggestions are shown? You *do* use the `git` and `python` keywords, and both tags have more activity (375k and 50k posts, respectively) than `mercurial` does (only 6.5k).

Comment: My guess is because the System saw `git` and `python` in the body of the question. `git` was also in the title of the question. From that it would make sense that `git` would be suggested over `mercurial`, note that there isn't some super AI that can interpret what the question means, it just looks at the words, matches tags, then picks the popular ones.

Comment: [Related question on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206907/how-are-suggested-tags-chosen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it doesn't actually *understand* your question; it just applies the available learned map to your question. In this case, your question came out as [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). With machine learning, there isn't really much of an "explanation" of anything, other than *that is what came out* (influenced by the input data and the corpus of data used for learning). Ultimately, they are only the *suggested* tags...